Why $f^\lambda$ in the hook-length formula?
This is my first question on this site so I apologize if it’s not adequate for it.
I just learned the hook-length formula for the number $f^\lambda$ of Standard Young Tableaux of shape $\lambda$:
$$f^\lambda=\frac{|\lambda|!}{\prod_\limits{x}\operatorname{hook}(x)}$$
where the product is over all boxes of the diagram.
Why is the letter $f$ used as standard notation? I’ve seen it on Stanley’s EC. I’d like to know the rationale behind this choice of letter.

I don't know the history, but it's already called $f$ in Alfred Young's QSA (On Quantitative Substitutional Analysis) III paper (1928).

@darijgrinberg From reading that paper not very closely, it seems like this $f$ is just the usual $f$ for a generic function. But perhaps we could retroactively attribute the meaning $f$ for "Frobenius"
